# Adding two different digit Numbers in c# ( without using BigInteger)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a Task to do C#. I need to add two numbers.

The first number contains around 100 digits like "12822429847264872649624264924626466826446692............"

and second number also with 100 digits or more or less

by using this numbers i need task like add/sub/multiply/div

I done this using `BigInteger` in C#

But do I need to do this using arrays or strings?

Comment: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: That is a good **Homework**

Comment: I edited My Code , that's Working But Very Big code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are both 100 digits just start with the last digit and in a for loop just add each one, but if the value is > 10 then remember to add one to the next digit.

This is how children learn to add, you just need to follow the same steps, but the answer should be in an array of 101 characters.

**UPDATE:**

Since you have shown some code now, it helps.

First, don't duplicate the code based on if str1 or str2 is larger, but make a function with that logic and pass in the larger one as the first parameter.

Determine the largest size and make certain the smaller value is also the same size, to make math easier.

The smaller one should have leading zeroes (padding), again to help keep the code simple.

Comment: They're both around 100 digits, not exactly 100 digits. Still, the same principle applies (just logically fill in the extra space with zeroes).

Comment: value > 10 equals to the "carry". Result can be either 100 or 101

Comment: How can i add carry and all other , can You tell me , speaking truth today only i start my programming, and start learning c#,

Comment: I edited My Code , that's Working But Very Big code, How can i Make it Simple

Answer (score 0):

You can also start by looking at the source code for structures such as `BigInteger`. They would provide you more insight into aspects such as computational efficiency and storage, particularly about multiplication and division. You can take a look at [here](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36323/BigInt).

Comment: I want to do With Out BigInteger

Comment: I know, but studying existing code will help.